# How to count best sold products in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Let's say I have this table with order lines:

**order_lines**
*- id*
*- order_id*
*- product_id*
*- quantity*

It contains all lines per order which contain a quantity *x* of product *y*.

Now I want to calculate out of these order lines which products are best sold. I am trying to write a query which does this efficiently.

Maybe something similar to this? It's just a guess.

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_id, COUNT(SUM(quantity)) as q FROM order_lines ORDER BY q DESC
```

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say 'best sold' do you mean highest quantity or number of orders?

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean :)

Comment: That's not a yes or no question. Do you mean highest quantity or number of orders?

Comment: Total quantity of all orders summed

Comment: Then check the answer you have, you just want to SUM(quantity) and group by product_id.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although "best sold" is subjective I will treat it as most sold product's for all given order's, In this case you need to do the `SUM` with `Group By` and it will give you the query.

```
SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) As MostSold 
FROM order_lines 
Group By product_id
ORDER BY MostSold  DESC
```

And if you want highest number of orders for each product then you can go as,

```
SELECT product_id, Count(product_id) As MostSold 
FROM order_lines 
Group By product_id
ORDER BY MostSold  DESC
```

Comment: I combined both queries to order by quantity first and by number of orders secondly.